# 300k POST requests in python

Tags: python, mysql, networking, ssl, httprequest

I'm trying to do around 300k POST requests. The problem of course is the performance.
So I get the data from MySQL db and then I do POST requests to the one of the API endpoints.
This is what I came out with in the very beginning, basically getting all of the data from the db and then read it row by row and every time I get the row I make a POST request. Obviously having 300k rows it takes ages.

```
def post_request(payload):
    r = requests.post(settings.api_host + "ppl.json", data=payload)
    response_data = json.loads(r.text)
    with open("./data/db.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(response_data + "\n\n")

for row in results:
    data_json = {
        "access_token": settings.access_token,
        "name": row[0],
        "age": row[1]
    }

    post_request(data_json)
```

So to speed up the process I tried doing something like:

```
payloads = []

for row in results:
    data_json = {
        "access_token": settings.access_token,
        "name": row[0],
        "age": row[1]
    }
    payloads.append(data_json)


pool = multiprocessing.Pool(5)
pool.map(send_data, payloads)


def send_data(payload):
    r = requests.post(settings.api_host + "ppl.json", data=payload)
    response_data = json.loads(r.text)
    with open("./data/db.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write(response_data + "\n\n")
```

and this way is also very slow...
also in both above examples I get into
`requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`
after around 1000 requests

any solutions on how to solve performance and SSL issues?

Comment: using some sort of queue to limit how many posts to send out at a time may be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to understand where is the bottleneck, is it the reponse time? too many requests at the same time? I tried to vary tthe `Pool(value)` but it doesn't make any difference